# Maven fails downloading with non-set version variable

Tags: maven, maven-2, pom.xml

I am trying to build a project of Maven2.0 with google-oauth-client-1.25.0.jar.

It fails with variable-looking path like

```
Downloading: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/oauth-client/google-oauth-client/${project.oauth.version}/google-oauth-client-${project.oauth.version}.pom
```

In my m2Repository, I got

- com.google.oauth-client.google-oauth-client

  - 1.25.0

    - google-oauth-client-1.25.0.jar
    - google-oauth-client-1.25.0.pom
    - (nothing else)

In the "google-oauth-client-1.25.0.pom", I wrote

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 
  <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.25.0</version>
</project>
```

In the project pom, I wrote,

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.25.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then, when I build, I get,

```
Downloading: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/oauth-client/google-oauth-client/${project.oauth.version}/google-oauth-client-${project.oauth.version}.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:pom:${project.oauth.version}' in repository central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

Could someone help me fix the problem?

Comment: Which Maven version are you using?

Comment: Im using 2.0.11.

Comment: Then please upgrade to a modern Maven version, like 3.6.3. Your Maven is probably more than ten years old.